# Visual C++ unresolved external symbol (can't find one of my own functions)

Tags: visual-c++, linker-errors

This is a very basic problem that's frustrating me at the moment. Let's say within a single solution, I have two projects. Let's call the first project SimpleMath. It has one header file "Add.h" which has

```
int add(int i, int j)
```

and the implementation "Add.cpp" which has

```
int add(int i, int j) {
  return i+j;
}
```

Now let's say in a second project I want to use the add function. However, this code:

> **#include "..\SimpleMath\Add.h"**

```
int main() {

    add(1, 2);

}
```

results in "unresolved external symbol". How do I get the second program to "know" about the actual implementation in the .cpp file. As a side note all code is fictional this is not how I actually program.

Answer (score 6):

The reason for the error you're getting is that by including the header file you're telling the compiler that there is a symbol

```
int add (int, int)
```

That will be present during linkage, but you haven't actually included that symbol (the code for the function) in your project. A quick way to resolve the issue is to simply add Add.cpp to both projects. But the "nice" solution would probably be to make SimpleMath into a library instead of an application by changing the project type in the project properties.

And by the way, you probably want some sort of mechanism in place to prevent multiple inclusion of that header file in place. I usually use `#pragma once` which should be fine if you stick with Visual C++ but that might not be entirely portable so if you want portability, go with the more traditional approach of wrapping the header file in an `#ifndef`-block, as such:

```
#ifndef __ADD_H
#define __ADD_H

int add (int i, int j);

#endif
```

Good luck.

Comment: Newer compilers support #pragma once directive; one can use it instead of header guard.

Comment: Newer ones maybe, but the old ones still don't. So it's not portable.

Answer (score 6):

If you're trying to link C libraries into C++ projects, you'll need to do something like

```
extern "C" {
    #include "..\SimpleMath\Add.h"
}
```

as C and C++ use different symbol names.

Answer (score 4):

You either have to make Add.cpp part of a library and include it in both projects. or you have to add Add.cpp to your second project too.

Edit: to make SimpleMath a library go into the project settings on General and change the Configuration Type to Static Lib.

Then go into your solution settings, click on Project Dependencies, then select your second project in the drop down list, and put a check mark next to SimpleMath. That will automatically link SimpleMath to your second project, and will also make sure that any changes to SimpleMath will be rebuilt when you rebuild your second project.

Answer (score 1):

SimpleMath would need to be defined as a library file (.LIB) in it's project properties I'm assuming that this is an unmanaged (non-.Net) C++.  Then include SimpleMath.lib in the other project.

Comment: I apologize for the necropost, but this seems to be the most relevant answer for what I'm trying to do.  What is the syntax for including a library?  Just `#include "MyLibrary.lib`?

Answer (score 1):

Just had it in the same project aswell, turns out I had two filters and named two .cpp-files **the same name**. So Visual Studio just overwrote one .obj while compiling the other. Resulting into missing functions in the first .obj. Lesson: never name .cpp-files the same, even in different folders/filters.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem **within the same project**... After looking closely at my code I notices that the code trying to call the function was **using an interface** (through a pure virtual method call = 0).  However, **I forgot to add the "virtual" word** in the interface class and the implementation class.  Once I added the "virtual" the problem was solved.